# CarrierWave attributes that are not in the database is always equal to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, null

I am use Rails 4.0.0 with CarrierWave gem. 
Why are the attributes that are not in the database is always equal to nil?
It is only within the file PostUploader. Ultimately, the data arrives. How to make sure that these attributes are available in the file PostUploader?

```
class PostUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
...
  version :thumb do
    process :crop
  end

  def crop
    model.image_crop # => nil
  end
...
end
```

model:

```
validates :name, presence: true
mount_uploader :image, PostUploader
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
```

controller:

```
def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   ...
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
end
```

`post_params
    {"name"=>"trololo", "image"=>#, @original_filename="large (3).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"large (3).jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "crop_x"=>"0", "crop_y"=>"0", "crop_w"=>"100", "crop_h"=>"200"}`

model object in PostUploader:

`Post id: nil, name: "trololo", image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil`

and

`model.crop_x && model.crop_w always => nil`

https://github.com/CandyDandy/Realty/tree/development This project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the reason(based upon your code ) for that is the way  assignment are working in tandem inside rails and carrierwave to explain in detail please observe the example below

```
class A
  attr_accessor :abuse_word,:word
  
  def initialize(abuse_word,word)
    self.word = word
    self.abuse_word = abuse_word
  end
  
  def word=(word)
    puts "Abuse word isnt set yet ...."
    puts "This will be nil => #{self.abuse_word}"
    @word = word
  end
end
```

O/p for the program is Like this

```
a1 = A.new("BAD","GOOD")
 => Abuse word isnt set yet ....
 => This will be nil => 
# But when you do this
a1.abuse_word
  => "BAD"
```

Now you can imagine something like this happening internally here what I meant

Considering this is your hash

```
{"name"=>"trololo", "image"=>#, @original_filename="large (3).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"large (3).jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "crop_x"=>"0", "crop_y"=>"0", "crop_w"=>"100", "crop_h"=>"200"}
```

No mind you `image=` (i.e your `uploader_column=` setter attributes is overridden by `Carrierwave` which internally call the processor which you have define i.e `crop`)

Now If you check the rails,rails does an `assign_attributes` based upon the hash passed to it check over [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L41-L49)

Now when rails does this (by parsing your params)

`image=[Value obtain from hash]` this invoke the method define by carrierave which internally call the

processor `crop` and hence you get the desired result as `crop_x` && `crop_w` always set to `nil` because the rails hasn't finish  with the assignment of  `image=` and is yet to assign `crop_x` and `crop_w` because in hash above they are after in the `image` key

So

`public_send("crop_x=",[desired_value])`
`public_send("crop_w=",[desired_value])`

is not been evaluate yet when your code reached to `processor` to process the image hence
when evaluating in processor `crop` you get there value as `nil`

## SOLUTION :

I suggest you do something like this in your controller

```
p1 = Post.new(post_params.except("image"))
p1.image = post_params.delete("image")
p1.save
```

Or else(I wont suggest this) make sure somehow make sure the `crop_x`,`crop_w`  are prior to `image` key in the post_params hash so your hash would look something like this

```
{"name"=>"trololo","crop_x"=>"0", "crop_y"=>"0", "crop_w"=>"100", "crop_h"=>"200", "image"=>#, @original_filename="large (3).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"large (3).jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
```

You can clearly identify the difference between the two

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much! You have helped me. Now everything works. You are my savior! :))

Comment: Good idea. Modifying `params` is a much better way to specify Carriewave attributes. You don't have to deal with attr methods or callbacks.